# I want it to go on to the next element in the array in a javascript quiz

Tags: javascript

So I have a bit of code, that once it finishes one question it stops is there anyway to once you pick a question and finish the question and get it right it goes on to the next question in the array, but if you get it wrong it stops.

I also have a small bug that when you enter in a question number, and spam the enter key it goes on to question 0 on the array

If you can help please do, and thanks in advance. I am 11 and started programming around a year ago.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
     <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Are you smarter than a 5th Grader?!!</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
     </head>
     <body onload="starter()" bgcolor="lightblue">
     <h1><marquee><font color="red">Make Trivia Great Again!</font>       
       </marquee></h1>
     <h2><em><center>Are You Smater Than a 5th Grader?</center></em></h2>
       <button onclick="sc()">Start</button><br>
       <p id="demo"> </p>
       <div id="result"></div>
       <button onclick="reset()">Reset Score</button>
       <script>
         function starter(){ 
           setTimeout("clickCounter()",100)
           setTimeout("minusCounter()",101)}
         function reset(){
           setTimeout("clickCounter()",100) 
           localStorage.clickcount=-1

         }
  function clickCounter() {
    if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {

      if (localStorage.clickcount) {
        localStorage.clickcount = Number(localStorage.clickcount)+1;
      } else {
        localStorage.clickcount = 0;
      }
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Score:"+                                      
             localStorage.clickcount 
           } else {
                  }   } 
      function minusCounter(){

        if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {

          if (localStorage.clickcount) {
            localStorage.clickcount = Number(localStorage.clickcount)-1;
          } else {
            localStorage.clickcount = 0;
          }
          document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Score:"+                               
          localStorage.clickcount 
        } else {
        } 
      }

         if (!("scramble" in Array.prototype)) {
           Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "scramble", {
             enumerable: false,
             value: function() {
        var o, i, ln = this.length;
        while (ln--) {
          i = Math.random() * (ln + 1) | 0;
          o = this[ln];
          this[ln] = this[i];
          this[i] = o;
        }
        return this;
             }
           });
         }
         var quiz = [{
           "question": ["Bug in the editor"],
           "choices": ["Please Ignore,Spam Enter or enter Cancel or Other"],
           "correct": ["Other"]
         }, {
                  "question": "Who is the founder of Microsoft?",
           "choices": ["Bill Gates", "Steve Jobs", "Steve Wozniak" , "Martin        
                 Shaba"],
           "correct": "Bill Gates"
         }, {
           "question": "What was your first dream?",
           "choices": ["8 bits", "64 bits", "1024 bits"],
           "correct": "8 bits"
         }, {
           "question": "The C programming language was developed by?",
           "choices": ["Brendan Eich", "Dennis Ritchie", "Guido van        
           Rossum"],
           "correct": "Dennis Ritchie"
         }, {
           "question": "What does CC mean in emails?",
           "choices": ["Carbon Copy", "Creative Commons", "other"],
           "correct": "Carbon Copy"
         }, {
           "question": "What is the full for of IP",
           "choices": ["Internet provider", "Intenet Port",               
          "Other","Internet                             Protocol"],
                  "correct": "Carbon Copy"
         }]
         function stop(){
           alert("stopped")
         }
   function sc(){
         quiz.forEach(q => q.choices.scramble());
         var x = prompt("Select Start question number #:");
               if (x>=6){
    alert("please pick a valid question")
                 sc()
         }
     else if (x<=5&&x>0){

     }

     else if(x=0){
       alert("please pick a valid question")
              sc()
     }

         else{alert("Please pick a valid question"),sc()}

         var ans = ""
         function myFunction(item, index) {
           ans += "\n[" + (index+1) + "]: " + item ; 
         }
         quiz[x].choices.forEach(myFunction);

         var y = prompt(quiz[x].question+"\nYour anwser is:"+ans);

         if (y == quiz[x].correct){
           alert("Correct!")
           clickCounter()

         }
            else if(y=="Cancel"){alert("canceled")}
     else{
           alert("Wrong! Please Try Again.");
           repeat()
         }
     function repeat(){
       quiz.forEach(q => q.choices.scramble());
       var ans = ""
       function myFunction(item, index) {
         ans += "\n[" + (index+1) + "]: " + item ; 
       }
       quiz[x].choices.forEach(myFunction);

       var y = prompt(quiz[x].question+"\nYour anwser is:"+ans);

       if (y == quiz[x].correct){
         alert("Correct!,Good Job")
         clickCounter()


       }
       else if(y=="Cancel"){alert("canceled")}
       else{
         alert("Sorry! \nThe right answer is "+quiz[x].correct);

       }
     }

   }

      </script>


     </body>
   </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, welcome to the world of programming, young programmer :)

Before giving a solution to your question, I would give you the following advice:

**Tidy up your code.** You might think you need a lot of time and effort to do this, but the truth is - you end up saving a lot of time debugging.

Professional programmers actually have most of their time spent of planning and debugging, but not coding itself. So it's important to make debugging easy. The first step to do this is to write tidy code.

Your question nicely demonstrates this: you don't know what's wrong happening and *you can't see it*. (It's also a pain for anyone else to read and help)

It's actually two simple problems:

1. You have a infinite-looping function call on your `sc()` function
   In the else-if case of `var x`, you need to add a return to leave the function.
2. You almost always trigger this infinite-loop by mistyping `x = 0` instead of `x == 0`
   (Assuming you know that `x = 0` is not the same as `x == 0`)

So the following is the code involved:

```
        if (x >= 6) {
            alert("please pick a valid question")
            sc()
        } else if (x <= 5 && x > 0) {

        } else if (x == 0) { // x = 0 is assignment, not comparison
            alert("please pick a valid question")
            sc()
            return;  // You have to 'return' here
                     // otherwise the code following the else would continue to execute after this inner-sc() returns
        } else {
            alert("Please pick a valid question"), sc()
        }
```

Also, there were newlines in the strings of your quiz array.
I'm not sure if it's just your copy & pasting to Stack Overflow which added these newlines, but if not, strings should not contain newlines. If you need to add newlines, use the newline character `\n` (back-slash n)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I did not understand your question clearly.
Could you tell me more about it?

If you mean that when you try to type answer option in number and it never returns true then your compared the `number` and the `"correct" string`.

You should try to compare the same data type to get the desired result.

Comment: Its a comment not answer

Comment: He probably does not have enough rep to comment.

Comment: Yes, I do not have enough reputation to comment :(