# After A trivia goes in a full cycle it stops

Tags: javascript

So I have been trying to make a Javascript quiz where once you pick a question, and goes back to that question later, It stops the quiz. Whenever I tried it, it would stop the quiz during the first attempt. I am 11 and started programming around 9 months ago. Thanks in Advance! it sounds like a previous question I asked, but there I didn't really understand  how to stop after a full cycle

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Are you smarter than a 5th Grader?!!</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

 <body onload="starter()" bgcolor="lightblue">
<h1><marquee><font color="red">Make Trivia Great Again!</font></marquee></h1>
<h2><em><center>Are You Smater Than a 5th Grader?</center></em></h2>
<button onclick="sc()">Start</button>
<br>
<p id="demo"> </p>
<div id="result"></div>
<button onclick="reset()">Reset Score</button>
<script>

    function starter() {
        setTimeout("clickCounter()", 100)
        setTimeout("minusCounter()", 101)
    }

    function reset() {
        setTimeout("clickCounter()", 100)
        localStorage.clickcount = -1

    }

    function clickCounter() {
        if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {

          if (localStorage.clickcount) {
            localStorage.clickcount = Number(localStorage.clickcount) + 1;
          } else {
            localStorage.clickcount = 0;
          }
          document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Score:" + localStorage.clickcount
        } else {}
    }

    function minusCounter() {

        if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {

            if (localStorage.clickcount) {
                localStorage.clickcount = Number(localStorage.clickcount) - 1;
            } 
            else {
                localStorage.clickcount = 0;
            }

            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Score:" + localStorage.clickcount
        } else {

        }
    }

    if (!("scramble" in Array.prototype)) {
        Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "scramble", {
          enumerable: false,
          value: function() {
            var o, i, ln = this.length;
            while (ln--) {
              i = Math.random() * (ln + 1) | 0;
              o = this[ln];
              this[ln] = this[i];
              this[i] = o;
            }
            return this;


          }
        });
    }

    var quiz = [{
        "question": "When was the first apple computer made?",
        "choices": ["1904", "1976", "1978", "2004"],
        "correct": ["1976"]
      }, {
        "question": "Who is the founder of Microsoft?",
        "choices": ["Bill Gates", "Steve Jobs", "Steve Wozniak", "Martin Shaba"],
        "correct": "Bill Gates"
      }, {
        "question": "What was your first dream?",
        "choices": ["8 bits", "64 bits", "1024 bits"],
        "correct": "8 bits"
      }, {
        "question": "The C programming language was developed by?",
        "choices": ["Brendan Eich", "Dennis Ritchie", "Guido van Rossum"],
        "correct": "Dennis Ritchie"
      }, {
        "question": "What does CC mean in emails?",
        "choices": ["Carbon Copy", "Creative Commons", "other"],
        "correct": "Carbon Copy"
      }, {
        "question": "What is the full for of IP",
        "choices": ["Internet provider", "Intenet Port", "Other", "Internet Protocol"],
        "correct": "Other"
      }];

    function stop() {
        alert("stopped")
    }

    function setter() {
        for (x = 1; x < 7; x++) {
          uc();
        }
    }


    var q;
    function sc() {
        q = prompt("start question #", "")
        if (q >= 6) {
          alert("please pick a valid question")
          sc()
        } else if (q <= 5 && q > 0) {
          ec()
        } else if (q == 0) {
          alert("please pick a valid question")
          sc()
          return;

        } else {
          alert("Please pick a valid question"), sc()
        }
    }

    var x;
    function ec() {
        console.log('ec');
        for (x = q; x < 7; x++) {
           if (x == 6) {
                setter()

                } else if (x==y) {
                  alert("done. You score was is:"+localStorage.clickcount)
                  return
            } else {
                  uc()
            }
        }
    }

    function uc() {
        console.log('uc');
        quiz.forEach(q => q.choices.scramble());
        var ans = ""

        function myFunction(item, index) {
          ans += "\n[" + (index + 1) + "]: " + item;
        }
        quiz[x].choices.forEach(myFunction);
        var y = prompt(quiz[x].question + "\nYour anwser is:" + ans);
        if (y == quiz[x].correct) {
          alert("Correct!")
          clickCounter()
        } else if (y == "Cancel") {
          alert("canceled")
          page.reload()
        } else {
          alert("Wrong! Please Try Again.");
          repeat()
        }
    }

    function repeat() {
        quiz.forEach(q => q.choices.scramble());
        var ans = ""

        function myFunction(item, index) {
        ans += "\n[" + (index + 1) + "]: " + item;
        }
        quiz[x].choices.forEach(myFunction);
        var y = prompt(quiz[x].question + "\nYour anwser is:" + ans);
        console.log(y);
        console.log(quiz[x].correct);
        if (y == quiz[x].correct) {
            alert("Correct!,Good Job")
            clickCounter()
        } else if (y == "Cancel") {
            alert("canceled")
        } else {
            alert("Sorry! \nThe right answer is " + quiz[x].correct);
        }
    }


</script>


</body>

 </html>
```

Comment: Weve answered your question twice times already...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I want it to go on to the next element in the array in a javascript quiz](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44059711/i-want-it-to-go-on-to-the-next-element-in-the-array-in-a-javascript-quiz)

Comment: Also have a look at my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44087924/go-on-to-the-next-element-in-a-javascript-quiz-so-whenever-it-finishes-one-it-go it already shows a possible solution ( just a tweak needed to stop after one iteration)